# "Error: Calling parameters do not match signature" when using ajax-jquery in iphone web app

Tags: magento, jquery, xml-rpc, iphone, iphone-web-app

In creating a iphone web app, i used [magento XML RPC](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-XMLRPC)to call magento web services. With the help of [jQuery XML RPC](https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc) i can access the magento web services.My code,

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"></link>
<script src="js/jquery.xmlrpc.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
   $.xmlrpc({
          url:"link of my magento/xmlrpc",
          methodName:'login',
          params:['user','pass'],
          success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
                  var res=response;
                  alert(res); // getting alert as session id as login response
             $.xmlrpc({
                       url:"link of my magento/xmlrpc",
                       methodName:'call',

               //passing session id from the previous response
                       params:{sessionId:res,methodName:'customer.info',customerId:'3'},
                       success: function(response1, status1, jqXHR1) {alert("success:"+response1);},
                       error: function(jqXHR1, status1, error1) {alert(error1); }
                   });
                },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {alert(error); }
         });
     });
 });

</script>
```

Here my problem is, when i run the app i get the session id and pass the id to next method "call" with the parameters.This code while executing gives me an error stating **"Error: Calling parameters do not match signature"**

I changed the way of passing parameters too but no hope. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug.

Take a look at this thread: [Calling parameters do not match signature](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40743/)

Comment: I tried with commenting the lines as said in that now it states error as "Error: Session Expired. Try to relogin